# ICSharpCode.TextEditor - Change Syntax Colors

Tags: c#, syntax-highlighting, icsharpcode

I'm using the ICSharpCode.TextEditor and want to change the syntax colors...
in the namespace

```
ICSharpCode.TextEditor.Document
```

there is the

```
public class HighlightColor
```

but I don't know how to give new colors to the editor. Somebody there, who knows how to do this or where I can find a documentation for that editor control?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax highlighting in ICSharpCode.TextEditor is determined by the syntax highlighting definition (.xshd file) used for the highlighting.

See [http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/Syntax highlighting.ashx](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/Syntax%20highlighting.ashx) for a description of the file format and how to load it into the text editor.

If you download the SharpDevelop source code, you can find the existing highlighting definitions in SharpDevelop\src\Libraries\ICSharpCode.TextEditor\Project\Resources.